# reading stdout in pipeline using "-" fails for "docker exec"

Tags: pipe, docker, stdout

I want to launch a bash terminal for my Docker instance by piping the first container ID to docker exec:

```
docker ps | head -2 | grep -v CONTAINER | cut -d' ' -f1 | docker exec -i -t - bash
```

The final `-` is supposed to pass the stdout of the previous pipeline process as a variable. But instead I get:

```
Error response from daemon: no such id: -
```

I would guess that the `docker` program interferes with how the shell reads the args.

Is there a way around this? (either via the `docker` program or a shell solution).

---

**Additional information**

This subpipeline:

```
docker ps | head -2 | grep -v CONTAINER | cut -d' ' -f1
```

produces output:

```
7dae6507d01a
```

which is correct. So no trouble here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-` isn't parsed by the shell, it is just an argument some commands recognize as "read from stdin". Apparently, docker doesn't.

You need to use xargs to pass the id as a real argument here. This should work:

```
 docker ps | head -2 | grep -v CONTAINER | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs -I '{}' docker exec -i -t '{}' bash
```

Comment: Silly me - I was trying to get too clever with use of `-` which I recently learned, while for years I've been using `xargs` even with `-I`! Curse of knowledge.